# Using debugger in MakeFile

Tags: c, debugging, makefile

I've written an entire program and its makefile, the only trouble is I have to idea how to implement the debugger. I've been looking at similar questions online but to no avail.

Here's my makefile:

```
#  the variable CC is the compiler to use.
CC=gcc 
#  the variable CFLAGS is compiler options.
CFLAGS=-c -Wall 

assign4: main1.o ObjectManager.o
    $(CC) main1.o ObjectManager.o -o assign4

main1.o: main1.c ObjectManager.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main1.c

ObjectManager.o: ObjectManager.c ObjectManager.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) ObjectManager.c

clean:
    rm -rf *o assign4
```

I've tried to adjust the CFLAGS: to -g Wall, but all it says is:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_main", referenced from:
>        implicit entry/start for main executable
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   make: *** [ObjectManager.o] Error 1

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: do you have a main() in main.c?

Comment: Also, debugging a c program is normally done with gdb. You just compile your program, then run it like so: gdb assign4

Answer (score 2):

Look at this rule:

```
ObjectManager.o: ...
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) ObjectManager.c
```

If `CFLAGS` is `-c -Wall`, that -c means that gcc will compile the source file, but not attempt to link it. **This is exactly what was intended, to produce an object file and not an executable.** One consequence of this is that the source dile (`ObjectManager.c`) need not contain a `main` function-- the compiler trusts you to provide one at link time.

But if `CFLAGS` is `-g -Wall`, the -g does *not* imply -c. So gcc will attempt to create an executable, and abort if `main` is not present.

Solution:

```
CFLAGS := -Wall -g # the -g can be added with a conditional if you like

ObjectManager.o: ...
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c ObjectManager.c
```

Comment: Since the makefile is using `gcc` to compile/link and `gdb` to debug,  suggest `CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -ggdb` and adding to the end of each compile statement: `-I.`  (although the compiler, by default, will look in the local directory for header files that are #include'd using double quote marks